# Active Directory powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get this script to work in active directory. So basically its a script for adding multiple users to AD and put thems them in the desired security groups that allow them applications/permissions . The problem I have is that the password will not work. Everything sets up fine but when I try and test the log in information, the password is incorrect. Manually changing the password will then work.

SO the script first reads from a csv file to check that the user names already specified do not exist already.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 2):

According to Quest's documentation(http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/New-QADUser) the `-UserPassword` switch takes a plain string as an argument, so you only need to use `-UserPassword "Password1"`.

*SecureString* is required for `New-ADuser` which is a part Microsoft's Powershell AD module.

Comment: SO then would I just need -UserPassword "Password1"  ??

Comment: Then you just need to change `New-QADUser` command to `New-QADUser -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -UserPrincipalName $userprinicpalname -Name $DisplayName -DisplayName $DisplayName -GivenName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -Description "Training Accounts" -Department "" -ParentContainer "OU=Trainee Users,OU=Department,DC=iwater,DC=ie" -UserPassword "Password1"` to create new users with password set to _Password1_

Comment: Well, investigate these and if you can't fix them edit your question or post a separate one. You might have a different version of Quest's cmdlets but reading the documentation and investigating errors is a good place to start troubleshooting problems.

Comment: @user3470150 - PowerShell 101: read error messages. Online questions 101: 'window full of errors' won't get you far. 'I get a lot of errors XXX' will (back to first suggestion). I'm **guessing** errors are there because your password is not following password policy.